# CSS container errors everywhere - Javascript appears when page has shrunk

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, containers

having an issue with a javascript element.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Account" data-widget-id="395882390205108224">Tweets by @Twitter</a><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
// ]]></script>
```

This is linked in with my other question I think but not 100% as this is regarding the JS element.

On JSFiddle it works fine, I can shrink the element and it appears. On my website it doesn't appear unless I shrink the browser down.

http://jsfiddle.net/MLJpY/

**Before**:

[image: before]

**After**:

[image: after]

URL: http://profiledt.co.uk/SetTraining/

Comment: "On JSFiddle it works fine" ... how can we check then the problem?

Comment: I added the site URL as a comparison to see what's wrong. I would add the CSS and HTML however it would clutter the thread with the pictures

Comment: Looks to me like a CSS issue thats causing the overlap.

Comment: The problem exists in this selector... In specific the height you have defined there.  Remove the height and a twitter feed appears and fixes your layout issue when shrinking the screen.  Why is this twitter feed hidden by giving it a height smaller than it needs? 

#frontpage-Button-Cont {
height: 135px;
}

Comment: Thanks Michael Stefan fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned a fixed height to the container for this elements.

CSS:

```
#frontpage-Button-Cont {
width: 100%;
height: 135px;
text-align: center;
}
```

the height attribute (works in chrome then) or add `overflow: auto` to have it in a container with scroll bars

```
#frontpage-Button-Cont {
width: 100%;
height: 135px;
text-align: center;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You Genius! I could kiss you! Thanks for that I completely had a brain fart adding a fixed height to the container instead of the content! 

Thanks Stefan!

Comment: You are welcome (and quickly updated your site). Please accept my anser then :). Maybe I sould stay in web development then and not change jobs ;D